# Android studio loses connection to device saying IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

My flutter android application seems to quit soon after loading with following error message. I am using google maps in my application and this happens soon after the maps load. I can see the map but can't seem to press +/- zoom button on the map. So, I am not sure if the map is loading completely with success. But because I see the map, I believe API keys are set up correctly. I have spent days trying to figure this out. So, any help appreciated. Following is error message and configuration file for my project.

```
[+4906 ms] W/GmsClient(30295): IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295): android.os.DeadObjectException
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.IGmsServiceBroker$Stub$zza.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:13)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:257)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:11)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zap.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.2.1:8)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
[        ] W/GmsClient(30295):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

App level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.fair.riderapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //-> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    // Add the SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging
    //-> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
    // <-
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Project level build graddle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //->classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        //->classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        //<-
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager' &&
                        !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

project level gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: abc_xyz_app
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7 #any
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1 #^0.8.4+5
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1 #any
  flutter_map: ^0.10.1 #any
#  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+2
  location: ^3.0.2 #^2.3.5
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.17 #^0.0.14
  http: ^0.12.2 #^0.12.0+2
  uuid: ^2.2.0 #^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^5.3.2+2 #^5.1.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  provider: ^4.3.1 #^3.0.0+1
  geocoder: ^0.2.1 #^0.1.2
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.4 #^0.2.3
  geoflutterfire: ^2.1.0 #any
  get_it: ^4.0.2 #^1.0.3+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8 #^0.5.3+4
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1 #^4.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16 #^4.0.0+1
  flutter_mapbox_autocomplete: ^1.0.4 #^1.0.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3 #^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/FAYR_logo.png
    - assets/greencar.png
    - assets/loading.gif
```

Comment: same issue? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Started today. service was working just fine. Could it be an update on gooogl  services

Google Maps Android API(12315): Google Play services package version: 202414019
D/AbsListView(12315): Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/GmsClient(12315): IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
W/GmsClient(12315): android.os.DeadObjectException

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this too and I wonder if it might be related to some memory leak. There is [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103870) in GitHub that looks related.